# Why python chose to access different members (static or instance members) based on when they are set

Tags: java, python, static

I am coming from classical OOP world - Java, C# etc. And I have been fiddling with some basic python stuff for a while. I wrote this basic code:

```
class MyClass:
    def createInstanceMember(self):
        self.member = "instance member"

    def createClassMember(self):
        MyClass.member = "class member"

    def printMember(self):
        print(self.member)

    def printStaticMember(self):
        print(MyClass.member)
```

Now when I do following:

```
myObj = MyClass()
myObj.createClassMember()
myObj.printMember()
myObj.createInstanceMember()
myObj.printMember()
myObj.createClassMember()
myObj.printMember()
myObj.printStaticMember()
```

It prints this:

```
class member
instance member
instance member
class member
```

But when I do this:

```
myObj.createInstanceMember()
myObj.printMember()
myObj.createClassMember()
myObj.printMember()
myObj.printStaticMember()
```

It prints:

```
instance member
instance member
class member
```

Here, when I call `createInstanceMember()` first, `printMember()` can never print class member. And it can print class member, as long as `createInstanceMember()` is not called. So, even though I understand why this behavior is happening, I feel its a bit weird and somewhat inconsistent in language design perspective. *Why certain variable reference should access different memory locations based on order of execution sequence of other statements?* Is there any specific reason / design choice, why python designers chose to make it that way? Or I am interpreting it plain wrong?

**PS:** In classical OOP languages, say in Java, this is not at all the case. There, static members are operated very differently, albeit more consistently (or its just my head dictating Java's behavior is more consistent). In Java, we cannot have instance and static member with same name.

Comment: the implementation of `myObj.printStaticMember()` is missing... (but, ok, we can all guess...).

Comment: It's not exactly a matter of order of execution (I mean it is in this case, but that is not what sets the rule). The rationale is "when reading a member, if there is an instance member with that name use that one; if not, if there is a class member with that name use that one". The confusing part is that the same logic does not apply when writing a member, in which case it is always considered to be an instance member.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist oops I forgot to paste some lines of code...added now.

Comment: side note: it's a 'gotcha' of static class variables in python that you can also access them with `self`... `class A: x = 4; a = A(); print(a.x)` (properly formatted) will print `4`. (as explained e.g. [here](https://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/class-and-instance-variables-in-python-2-7/)).